# Comparing dates stored as varchar

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I need to compare dates that are stored in my database as varchar against today's date.

Specifically,  I need to exclude any records with a date that has passed.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tblServiceUsersSchedule 
WHERE ScheduleEndDate !='' AND ScheduleEndDate < '2015/05/31'
```

This selected values such as 17/06/**2012** and 19/04/2015, which have both already passed, along with 01/06/2015 which hasn't.

I then tried to cast the data with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tblServiceUsersSchedule 
WHERE  CAST(ScheduleEndDate as DATETIME)  < CAST('05/31/2015' as DATETIME) AND ScheduleEndDate !='' AND ScheduleEndDate is not null
```

But got the following error:

> The coversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

I checked the data behind and none are null, none are blank white space. All are dates in the format of dd/mm/yyyy.

I can't figure out how to compare the varchar date stored with todays date.

Comment: You've explained exactly the type of problem of why storing dates as a `varchar` is a horrible practice.  You should update your database schema to use `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset` as appropriate.  Any answer given below, even those that *work*, will result in a [non-sargable query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - which means you cannot use an index.  The larger the table, the worse the performance will be - as it will always have to examine every row of the table to answer your query.  Use the correct type and avoid the problem.

Comment: I decided to use varchar as sometimes the a date of 01/01/1900 (or something like that) would be inserted. I knew it wasn't ideal at the time but feel sort of tied to it now

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think a `date` column couldn't hold `01/01/1900`.  Or if you meant that you might need a non-value, that's what `nullable` columns are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Storing date values as varchar is simply wrong.**

If possible, you should alter the table to store them as date data type.
You can do it in a few simple steps:

1. Rename the current columns (I'm guessing ScheduleStartDate is also varchar) to columnName_old. This can be easily done by using [`sp_rename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx).
2. Use [`alter table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) to add the columns with the appropriate data type.
3. Copy the values from the old columns to the new columns using an update statement. Since all of the dates are stored in the same format, you can use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) like this:  `set ScheduleStartDate = convert(date, NULLIF(ltrim(rtrim(ScheduleStartDate_old)), ''), 103)` If your sql server version is 2012 or higher, use [`try_convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx). Note i've used the [`nullif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx), [`ltrim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) and [`rtrim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) to convert values that only contains white spaces to null.
4. Drop and recreate indexes that is referencing these columns. The simplest way to do this is by right-clicking the index on SSMS and choose `script index as` -> `drop and create`.
5. Use `alter table` to remove the old columns.

**Note:** if these columns are being referenced in any other objects on the database you will have to change these objects as well. This includes stored procedures, foreign keys etc`.

**If you can't change the data types** of the columns, and your sql server version is lower then 2012, you need to use convert like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblServiceUsersSchedule 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, NULLIF(ScheduleEndDate, RTRIM(LTRIM('')), 103) 
      < CAST(GETDATE() As Date);
AND ScheduleEndDate IS NOT NULL
```

Note that if you have even a single row where the column's data is not in dd/MM/yyyy format this will raise an error.

For sql server versions 2012 or higher, use `Try_convert`. This function will simply return null if the conversion fails:

```
SELECT * FROM tblServiceUsersSchedule 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, NULLIF(ScheduleEndDate, RTRIM(LTRIM('')), 103)
      < CAST(GETDATE() As Date);
AND ScheduleEndDate IS NOT NULL
```

**Note:** I've used `CAST(GETDATE() as Date)` to remove the time part of the current date. This means that you will only get records where the `ScheduleEndDate` is at least one day old. If you want to also get the records where the `ScheduleEndDate` is today, use `<=` instead of `<`.

**One final thing:** Using functions on columns in the where clause will prevent Sql Server to use any indexing on these columns.
This is yet another reason why you should change your columns to the appropriate data type.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what people have already suggested that you should never store `DATETIME` as `VARCHAR`. Always store it in a `DATETIME` type column; I think you should change your condition in `WHERE`

```
ScheduleEndDate < '2015/05/31'
```

To this, in order to get all dates which hasn't passed yet

```
ScheduleEndDate >= '2015/05/31'
```

Your query should look like

```
SELECT * FROM tblServiceUsersSchedule 
WHERE ScheduleEndDate IS NOT NULL
AND ScheduleEndDate >= '2015/05/31'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you HAVE TO store your dates as varchar (and as per other other answers, this is a poor practice), then using an ISO style format like yyyy-mm-dd should allow textual comparisons without issue. 
If your column is a date data type, and you're using SQL 2012 or later then use DATEFROMPARTS (or one of its variants) for date comparison, so

```
WHERE DateToCompare < DATEFROMPARTS (2019, 12, 31)
```

rather than

```
WHERE DateToCompare < '2019-12-31'
```

SQL handles the latter fine, but the former is more "correct".