# I had assigned Varchar for date and It's not working when I select between range of dates

Tags: sql-server, date

```
Create Table Table_Name([Date] Varchar(100));

Standard 105.

Insert Into Table_Name Values('18-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('19-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('20-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('21-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-02-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-03-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-04-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-05-2015');

Select [Date] From Table_Name Where [Date] >= '18-01-2015' And [Date] <= '20-01-2015'
Select [Date] From Table_Name Where [Date] Between '18-01-2015' And  '22-01-2015'

Result is 

Date
18-01-2015
19-01-2015
20-01-2015
21-01-2015
22-02-2015
22-03-2015
22-04-2015
22-05-2015
```

This is my C# Code that how I get date.!

label17.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
If I try to insert it Date or Datetime datatype., the following error throws., Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is why I am supposed to use Varchar.

This is the query which I want.

SELECT * FROM Sundar_Tyre_Sale_Billing WHERE CONVERT(Date, [Date], 105) BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, '10-02-2015', 105) AND CONVERT(Date, '12-02-2015', 105) Order By [Date] ASC

Thanks everyone..!!

Comment: You need to put your values into **single quotes** when inserting!

Comment: Yeah done. I had completed the insert operation. The values got inserted.

Comment: Storing dates as varchar is a really bad idea and will never work correctly and you should also always use YYYYMMDD format since that works with all regional settings -- and also reserving varchar(100) for something that will never be 100 characters is also a bad habit.

Comment: I didn't expect the requirement between range of dates. Sorry JamesZ. I thought of casting or convert. It also didn't worked well.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: How to change column datatype in SQL Server database without losing data

Any Alter Column possible. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that they are not working is because you use the **wrong** data type in the first place.
Never use `Varchar` to store `date` or values.
Always use the appropriate data type for your data (in this case, `Date` seems to be what you are looking for, assuming your sql version is 2008 or higher. if it's 2005 or lower, you should either upgrade your sql server to a supported version, or use `DateTime`).

Also, when specifying dates as string literals, always use ANSI-SQL format (`yyyy-mm-dd`), since it will never be ambiguous (is `02/04/15` April 2nd or February 4th?)

Another thing, Date is a reserved word (as already stated).
Avoid using reserved words and it will save you a lot of time and work. [Here is my favorite method to avoid them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132058/3094533)

This is what I would do:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl_TableName(TableName_Date Date);

INSERT INTO Tbl_TableName VALUES
('2015-01-18'),
('2015-01-19'),
('2015-01-20'),
('2015-01-21'),
('2015-01-22')

Select Date From Table_Name Where Date >= '2015-01-18' And Date <= '2015-01-20'

Select Date From Table_Name Where Date Between '2015-01-18' And  '2015-01-20'
```

Comment: Already there is lot of date stored in this format. I accept the mistake is mine. Plz advice me how to get out of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Read this answer I gave to someone else in your situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559976/comparing-dates-stored-as-varchar/30569396#30569396)

Comment: This is my C# Code that how I get date.! label17.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); If I try to insert it Date or Datetime datatype., the following error throws., Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: SELECT * FROM Sundar_Tyre_Sale_Billing WHERE CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('10-02-2015' AS DATE) AND CAST('12-02-2015' AS DATE)

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can you please correct the mistake.!

Comment: Did you read the part of my answer where I wrote **"always use ANSI-SQL format (yyyy-mm-dd)"**?

Comment: Zohar Peled ., Thank you so much.

This is the query which I want.

SELECT * FROM Sundar_Tyre_Sale_Billing WHERE CONVERT(Date, [Date], 105) BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, '10-02-2015', 105) AND CONVERT(Date, '12-02-2015', 105) Order By [Date] ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Table_Name([Date] Varchar(100));

Standard 105.

Insert Into Table_Name Values('18-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('19-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('20-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('21-01-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-02-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-03-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-04-2015');
Insert Into Table_Name Values('22-05-2015');

Select [Date] From Table_Name Where [Date] >= '18-01-2015' And [Date] <= '20-01-2015'
Select [Date] From Table_Name Where [Date] Between '18-01-2015' And  '22-01-2015'

Result is 

Date
18-01-2015
19-01-2015
20-01-2015
21-01-2015
22-02-2015
22-03-2015
22-04-2015
22-05-2015
```

Comment: This will be a clear picture of what my problem is ..!!

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, please edit your question to include the information you want.

Comment: This is my C# Code that how I get date.!

label17.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

If I try to insert it Date or Datetime datatype., the following error throws.,

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.