# I want to change datatype of a column [varchar] to [datetime] in sql without losing the data

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I've tried to save the changes, but it gives this error:

> Saving changes is not permitted the changes you have made require the
>   following tables to be dropped and re - created. You have either...

for example,
   **PersonID**       **In_time**      **Out_time** 
 15001        10:00 AM    7:20 PM 
 15002        10:10 AM    7:10 PM 
 15003        10:15 AM    7:00 PM

The 'in_time' and 'out_time' field is in varchar(50)

I want to change datatype of a columns from `varchar` to `datetime`.

I just tried in GUI not in query.Because i am.., if i scripted anything wrong it becomes lost of datas so i am aware to do
I am new to sql. so please suggest me what to do..

Comment: Provide sample data what is stored in varchar column. Also are you using MySql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Column name is "In_TIme" value is 10:00 PM
I am using Sql server..

Comment: Wellcome to SO. For use to help you we need to see your code and the structure of your database. The only guess this far is, that you tried to do something where you don't have the required rights to. Maybe it will help you to check those out.

Comment: I tried to post image but it says "your reputation score is low.."
what should i do..? yes i am new to this.

Comment: Post code, not as an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing dates stored as varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559976/comparing-dates-stored-as-varchar)

Comment: Update your question with sample data, hard to understand from comments.

Comment: r u there @StanislovasKalašnikovas

Comment: You can't store in DATETIME column value like that `10:00 PM`, It will be converted to `1900-01-01 10:00:00.000` and later you can convert when selecting to format like that in following: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(Data AS TIME),100)`

Comment: Updated my answer with `CONVERT` which I provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create *TEMP* table to copy values from your table, after It copy values from table to temp table. After It you can truncate your table or column with dates, after It you can change datatype of nvarchar column to datetime, after It copy values from temp table to normal table, You can do something like:

```
-- Creation of sample table
CREATE TABLE ChangeColType
(
    Data NVARCHAR(20)
)

-- Inserting sample data 
INSERT INTO ChangeColType VALUES ('10:00 AM')

-- Creatig temp table
CREATE TABLE #TempValues
(
    Data NVARCHAR(50)
)

-- Copying values from table to temp table
INSERT INTO #TempValues
SELECT Data 
FROM ChangeColType

-- Truncating your table
TRUNCATE TABLE ChangeColType

-- Changing datatype of your column
ALTER TABLE ChangeColType
ALTER COLUMN Data DATETIME

-- Copying back values from temp table to your table
INSERT INTO ChangeColType
SELECT Data 
FROM #TempValues

-- Selecting values from table after datatype changed
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(Data AS TIME),100)   
FROM ChangeColType

-- Dropping temp table
DROP TABLE #TempValues
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the structure of your table by GUI please check this:

Tools menu -> Custom -> Go to Designers voice on the left menu opened with popup and remove the check "Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation".
[image: I add menu (in Italian version)]
[image: I add a screenshot (in Italian version)]

Comment: It says   - Warning: Data might be lost converting column 'intime' from 'varchar(50)'.
- Warning: Data might be lost converting column 'outtime' from 'varchar(50)'.