# How to compare date when its save as type text in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress, date

I am using **WPDB** and here is my **SQL**

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$reservations = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM reservation_db WHERE `date` > '$date'");
```

I need to select the date in my database when the date in database greater than today.
My date format is `dd-mm-yyyy`, but I think because it's save in text, it only compares days(dd) which is wrong, any solution to solve this?

Comment: Actually, this is not a good practice to follow. You should use `date` or `datetime` data type to save the date.

Comment: See this link it looks similar to your problem. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559976/comparing-dates-stored-as-varchar)

Comment: Thanks! I won't be do this again. Problem solve now. Appreciation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL offers a [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert a date string to date:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation_db WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`) > '$date'
```

But as ankit suthar mentioned in [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793138/how-to-compare-date-when-its-save-as-type-text-in-database/44793210#comment76566843_44793138), it is not recommended to store dates as text.