# Apply date filter on VARCHAR | SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem regarding to my existing database.

I have a DB structure in which the "Date column" is in **VARCHAR(10)** and I want to apply a date filter on this but as the date is saved as a string it is not working as it should be.
Due to some system constrains, I can't change the structure of DB or the format of date in it, it must stay as it is.

Structure of column is as below

```
`Date` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
```

Date format (in string) is like --> '10/22/2020'

Query I tried is below but it didn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM `documents2` WHERE  documents2.Date >= '11/15/2019' AND documents2.Date <= '11/15/2021'
```

I will be Thankful to you if anyone can tell me a way that I can apply date filter on a string.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: You'll have to use a conversion function of your DBMS to create a real date on the fly.

Comment: Dates stored in a VARCHAR is not the greatest idea for data integrity. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30569396/8328420 It has solutions to your question, but also tells you how to fix the type of the column to avoid this altogether.

Comment: Storing a date as a string (where it's not a date, just a string) is exceptionally bad for performance for any filtering criteria you may wish to perform; To perform any date comparison the database engine must first convert the string value to a proper date, so it must do that for every row *first*  - this is what's known as being *unsargable* and any query that does this will force the engine to scan the entire table/index.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: **Never**, ever store date values in a `varchar` column. This is a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a bad idea of storing date in VARCHAR. But it was already done and i had to work with it without changing the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use str_to_date function.
In a way like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `documents2` WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(documents2.Date,'%m/%d/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('11/15/2019','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(documents2.Date,'%m/%d/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('11/15/2021','%m/%d/%Y')
```