# I need to fetch the records that are between these DATE and DATE_TIME Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a AUDIT Table in Oracle with DATE_AND_TIME as DATE and DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT as Varchar2. I need to fetch records that are between two Date and DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT. for example

```
Record  Date_AND_TIME   DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
1   02-Feb-2022 13:35:24    
2   02-Feb-2022 13:35:56    
3   07-Feb-2022 13:35:32    
4   07-Feb-2022 13:35:23    
5   07-Feb-2022 13:35:02    
6   07-Feb-2022 13:36:02
```

I need the Query which will fetch me records 3,4,5 if I execute it for 03-FEB-2022 13:35:00 to 07-FEB-2022 13:35:00 and record 6 if I execute the query for 07-FEB-2022 13:36:00 to 12 07-FEB-2022 13:37:00.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data as you current text format is ambiguous as to what value is in which column; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing dates stored as varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559976/comparing-dates-stored-as-varchar)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have used the column's datatype like this. You can directly use the timestamp or Date column only which will contain the DateTime information in it. If you cannot change the datatype, You can use below query -

```
SELECT *
  FROM AUDIT
 WHERE Date_AND_TIME || ' ' || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
       BETWEEN TO_DATE('03-FEB-2022 13:35:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
           AND TO_DATE('07-FEB-2022 13:35:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: I have Ankit, Thank you for the query. I am getting below error while executing. It's client DB can't run any DDL commands. Thanks a ton!
 ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: "ORA-01830: date format picture ends" . . . and now you see one of the reasons why keeping a date/time in a varchar2 column is such a bad idea.  Ther is zero chance of guaranteeing that the "date/time" will be in a consistent, usable, predictable format.  If the column is a varchar2, oracle doesn't care what you think it should be, and will consider the value 'here''s yer sign' to be just as acceptable as '2022-02-07 15:43:21'.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store your time values in a `VARCHAR2` column. In Oracle, a `DATE` data type **ALWAYS** has the components year, month, day, hour, minute and second so you can store the time in the `DATE` column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Record        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Date_AND_TIME DATE
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (record, date_and_time)
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('02-Feb-2022 13:35:24', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE('02-Feb-2022 13:35:56', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('07-Feb-2022 13:35:32', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, TO_DATE('07-Feb-2022 13:35:23', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, TO_DATE('07-Feb-2022 13:35:02', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, TO_DATE('07-Feb-2022 13:36:02', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Then your query is simply:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_and_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('03-FEB-2022 13:35:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND     TO_DATE('07-FEB-2022 13:36:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_and_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('07-FEB-2022 13:36:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND     TO_DATE('07-FEB-2022 13:37:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abe37b4b7d6a6bc5a749f0c9ed3d4596)*